Modelling spatiotemporal data with GAMs (part II)
this post is a continuation of my previous question about modelling spatiotemporal data with GAMS:
Modelling spatiotemporal data with GAMs
In short, I am currently modelling a data set of house prices, where some of the important covariates are the house coordinates (x,y) and the date of the house sale, t. Following the suggestions from the previous post I have tried different GAM-specifications for modelling the spatiotemporal component. Below I describe each of these and the RMSE training-error obtained:
1) A trivariate spline based on the default thin-plate smooths in mgcv:
model1 <- mgcv::gam(price ~ s(x, y, t, k = 1500),
                    data = data,
                    family = Gamma(link=log),
                    method = "REML")

rmse <- sqrt(mean((model1$fitted.values - model1$y)**2))

print(rmse)
[1] 3495.282


2. A tensor-product spline as suggested in the previous post:
model2 <- mgcv::gam(price ~ te(x, y, t, d = c(2,1), k = c(500, 5), bs = c("tp", "cr")),
                    data = data,
                    family = Gamma(link=log),
                    method = "REML")

rmse <- sqrt(mean((model2$fitted.values - model2$y)**2))

print(rmse)
[1] 3745.546


3. A model without interaction between the spatial and temporal component:
model3 <- mgcv::gam(price ~ s(x, y, k = 500) +
                    s(t, k = 3),
                    data = data,
                    family = Gamma(link=log),
                    method = "REML")

rmse <- sqrt(mean((model3$fitted.values - model3$y)**2))

print(rmse)
[1] 3771.286


4. A model with interaction modelled as a separate tensor-product spline:
model4 <- mgcv::gam(price ~ s(x, y, k = 500) +
                    s(t, k = 3) + 
                    ti(x, y, t, d = c(2,1), k = c(500, 5), bs = c("tp", "cr")),
                    data = data,
                    family = Gamma(link=log),
                    method = "REML")

rmse <- sqrt(mean((model4$fitted.values - model4$y)**2))

print(rmse)
[1] 3753.491


Now, I am rather confused of these results. If the analysis makes sense, the conclusion is that the isotropic trivariate smooth in model 1 performs best. But this directly contradicts the answers in my previous post stating that the the default s() wrongfully assumes equal wigglyness in the spatial and temporal directions. Is there some obvious mistake in the above model specifications? Or is it that my comparison of training RMSEs is not meaningful? If the latter is the case, what is then the best way to compare the accuracy of the models? I have also checked the RMSE errors on an out-of-sample test set and the conclusions are the same, so it is NOT an issue of training/test errors.

You shouldn't assess a model's performance by using the training data as a test

Hi Gavin, as I wrote in the last line I also assessed the performance on an independent test set and the conclusions are the same.

There is nothing wrong. You have fit several candidate models and compared them on a single criterion. But unless your only goal is to generate reasonable predictions, you could also compare: 1) any inferences you might want to obtain from these models; 2) what kinds of assumptions they might make in terms of generalizing to potential future new data; 3) how sensitive these inferences are to your data preparation and modeling choices etc... Gavin has given you some guidance on different potential model specifications but it is not up to him to decide which is 'right' or 'wrong'

@AugustEdwards Sorry, I missed the last line. You're not really comparing like for like here. In the 3D TPRS you are allowing a massive amount of wiggliness in the time dimension that you don't allow for in the tensor product where you're only allowing 5 or 3 EDF per marginal basis for t. I would expect the s(x,y,t) to allow more wiggliness in time than any of the other models, so depending on how you defined your independent test set I could imagine situations where this overfitting wouldn't be caught (i.e. using time points that are in the training data)

What are you interested in doing with the model? If it's prediction or forecasting you can focus on predictive ability (although usual model diagnostics apply) but if you also want to do inference you really need to concentrate on model diagnostics & posterior checking of the model. With spatiotemporal data, CV is much more difficult as you need to leave out a whole block of space and a whole block of time, rather than just random splitting to $k$ folds. $h$-block CV is often used. Also consider if you are only interested in the conditional expectation (fitted "mean") or the distribution.

Hi Gavin,
thanks for the useful answers. I am interested in a model that makes as accurate predictions as possible but where the resulting smooths can be interpreted in a meaningful way.
I am a bit new to the area of statistics, so maybe you can elaborate a bit on the inference part. I would have naively assumed that the more accurate my model was the more trustworthy inference I could also do with it. When would this not be the case?

By inference I mean doing statistical testing on smooths, comparing smooths, etc because that comes with assumptions that your model needs to meet. If prediction is the goal, it is worth mentioning that you can get biased or underperforming prediction even for the mean price if you assume a fixed/constant scale/shape parameters of the distribution. So even if you're not interested in say the upper and lower quartiles of estimated price (for example), building a distributional model can improve your estimates of the expected price.

"I would have naively assumed that the more accurate my model was the more trustworthy inference." If you choose your model by looking at the data then the things we use for inferences aren't really "correct" any longer. It really depends on what you did to choose the model forms and how you did that choosing.
